# string tokenizer failing

Tags: c++, stl

Following is how I am using string tokenizer.

```
typedef std::string                      string_t;
typedef std::vector<string_t>            stations_t;

void Tokenize(const string_t& str, stations_t& tokens,const string_t& delimiters = " ") {
    string_t::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
    string_t::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    while (string_t::npos != pos || string_t::npos != lastPos){
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    }
}
```

When I am passing string `1,8003,1,HWH,Kolkata Howrah Junction,,16:10,,1,0` to this , it is returning me `8` fields, where as it should return `9` , it is complete ignoring `,,` part. Can anybody pls take a look and help me to find the bug here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provide, you want an empty field between "16:10" and "1", right?

The reason you are not getting it, is because when you gotten the sub-string "16:10", then `pos` is 43, and you look for a character not in the delimiter string starting at that position. The first non-delimiter character is the "1" at position 45.

I suggest something like this:

```
void Tokenize2(const string_t& str, stations_t& tokens,const string_t& delimiters = " ") {
    string_t::size_type elem_start = 0;
    string_t::size_type elem_end  = str.find_first_of(delimiters, 0);
    while (elem_start != string_t::npos && elem_end != string_t::npos) {
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(elem_start, elem_end - elem_start));
        elem_start = str.find_first_of(delimiters, elem_end) + 1;
        elem_end   = str.find_first_of(delimiters, elem_start);
    }

    if (elem_start != string_t::npos) {
        // Get the last element
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(elem_start, elem_end - elem_start));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in your logic of finding a token.

```
lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
```

Basically you try to find a character that is not a delimiter and assign it to **lastPos**, then  you proceed to find the first delimiter after **lastPos** and assign it to **pos** and grab everything between **lastPost** and **pos** to be a token.  Basically the act of trying to find **find_first_not_of** will skip any consecutive delimiters. You can use the test input

```
,,,,,,,,22,
```

and you will find that the first iteration finds the token **22** and skips all 
consecutive ","s

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) has plenty of ways to write a tokenizer